# Flutter & Dart plugin not installed error when running flutter doctor

Tags: flutter

I don't know how to fix this problem.

[image]

I tried to uninstall and install the Flutter & Dart plugin.

[image]

Comment: did you try restarting your android studio and then running `flutter doctor`

Comment: yes I did it but it not working

Comment: Is your Flutter app running? Sometimes I can run the app even I get the same error.